# Adding columns to a SSIS dtsx import

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Our SQL server was setup by an outside contractor who's no longer here and we can't get ahold of him.

There's a SSIS package that runs daily and imports a flat CSV into the SQL server. It's actually an extract from a partner company. They've added columns to the CSV and it's causing havoc with the daily import.

It's returning the following error messages:

- ImportTable:Error: An error occurred while skipping data rows.
- ImportTable:Error: The column delimiter for column "NickName" was not
  found.
- ImportTable:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The
  PrimeOutput method on ImportTable returned error code 0xC0202091.
  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
  PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
  component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
  There may be error messages posted before this with more information
  about the failure.

I've opened the SSIS package in Visual Studio and I can see where it's mapping columns from the CSV to a temporary import table in the SQL server, but I can't see the option to add the new columns? Can anybody give me some pointers?

Comment: You need to refresh the source first, and add the columns there, then in the data flow. Really you're going to need to read a few tutorials here, as there's a lot to updating an SSIS package.

Comment: *.csv files always have host of problems where column delimiters, column separators, invisible characters like null terminators \0, special characters based on encoding, and line breaks are in the middle of the actual data.
The most reliable format for data feeds is XML enforced by XSD. An XSD (as a data contract between sender and receiver) will guarantee data quality, and prevent unexpected changes.